Significant one letter edits
In Installed MacOSX over HDD containing wallet, there is a typo which will hinder searches.  Trying to edit it, I get a warning at the top of the page and a refusal at the bottom during submission.
This is a significant change - how can I make it?

Fixed it for ya.

Ironically this question itself has a single character error: "type" instead of "typo".

The error I got was "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"
You can reword another part of your post in addition to changing the single character and it should go through.

Yes but this is stupid: if there is only a single character to fix, I should be able to do it.
